# Are prediction markets kosher?

Tags: halacha, halacha-theory, transactions

What is the halachic status of [prediction markets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_market)? Are Jews allowed to employ them?

Comment: Do you have any reason to think they would be prohibited?

Comment: These things appear as black boxes to a lot of people. They may start putting faith in them.

Comment: Medications are black boxes too, to a lot of people.